# CodeIgniter not maintaining session when saved via ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I have a pretty basic code. I logged in using AJAX, I saved the session and it is being saved.

When I reload the page and do this

> echo $this->session->userdata('userID');

It shows me empty. This is my code

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = $config['sess_expiration'];
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I want my session to be maintained but it resets. Anyone faced a similar issue? I am using **v3.1.8**.

Comment: how do you understand that *and it is being saved* ?

Comment: I var_dumped it right after I was saving the session. It was working for that particular moment. When I try to use that session on another page, it shows empty.

Comment: Is there anything in your log file? Check that - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver

Comment: Like that problem is mostly caused by wrong config setting ! So try to modify your config one by one

Comment: `print_r($this->session->userdata)`

Comment: change `$config['sess_time_to_update']` to 300 and `$config['sess_save_path']` to `sys_get_temp_dir();`

Comment: i had same issue that was only pervasive on 1 server. try it on another setup to see if the issue persists, if it does, it is a config issue